# Help with finding speed and coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, coordinate-systems, velocity

Can you please help me with this I'm stuck?

A particle starts from rest at $t=0$ at the origin and moves in the XY plane with a constant acceleration of $a=( 2i+4j)\ \mathrm{m/sec^2}$

After a time of $3$ seconds has elapsed. find:

1. the $x$ and $y$ components of velocity.
2. the coordinates of the particle.
3. the speed of the particle.

Comment: Hi. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm not sure how to start

Comment: @RubaAbuGheith Maybe try breaking it down into two one-dimensional problems.

Answer (score 0):

Since the particle is moving under constant acceleration and you are dealing with vector quantities, you can use the [SUVAT equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#:%7E:text=They%20are%20often%20referred%20to,%3D%20acceleration%2C%20t%20%3D%20time.) in the two different directions ($i$ and $j$), to find the results you require.

These equations are derived from the definitions of acceleration

$$\vec a = \frac{d\vec v}{dt}$$

and velocity

$$\vec v = \frac{d\vec s}{dt}.$$